# Pythonic way set variables if none in __init__

Tags: python

What's the most pythonic or elegant way of achieving this?

```
def __init__(self, connection=None, some=None, thing=None, else=None):
   if connection is None:
      self.connection = SetConnection()
   else:
      self.connection = connection
.
.
```

If I have multiple input args like above for which I would like to call another class to instantiate. Any good way to keep it clean looking without being verbose?

Comment: I keep find it amazing how it is always the "simple" questions that raise so much traffic and ideas

Comment: you can use `isinstance` to check if `connection` is indeed the class/type you need and not something else.

Comment: @DeepSpace Indeed: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ternary operator

```
def __init__(self, connection=None, some=None, thing=None, else=None):
   self.connection = SetConnection() if connection is None else connection
```

Comment: Although other answer shows "simpler" solution, I ended up using this as it will not mislead when inputs are 0, False, [], (), {} and ''

Answer (score 4):

You could use a binary operator:

```
def __init__(self, connection=None, some=None, thing=None, else=None):
    self.connection = connection or SetConnection()
```

If connection is None *(False)* it will run `SetConnection()`.

Comment: This will only work as long as `False`,  `0`, empty list etc are not possible values. A single-liner that solves this is `self.connection = connection if connection is not None else SetConnection()`

Comment: Note that this assumes that all valid values of the parameter are truthy.

Comment: True, this does make assumptions based on input. Though he was asking for "Any good way to keep it clean looking without being verbose"

Comment: Why was this downvoted? The question clearly stated '... for which I would like to **call another class to instantiate**...' .. so `False`, `0`, empty list, etc., are already excluded.

Comment: While this approach has its limitations (indeed, it won't work if `connection` can have a valid non-`None` value that is not truthy, or if the `SetConnection` class defines `__bool__` in an unusual way), it's also in my experience very idiomatic. I've definitely seen a lot of code use `or` rather than a ternary expression for cases like this.

Comment: It does meet his requirements and the assumption I did make was that he was making a call to init himself.

Comment: It makes sense when you take his question's confinements into consideration. Thanks for taking my side, `or` has it's weakneses but it does make for "clean looking" code  and this is what he asked for

Comment: @Jaba There are no "sides" here. We are all here to learn and (hopefully) have fun. Please don't take anything personally.

Comment: Thanks, @DeepSpace it was just the first answer that made snese to me for the example in the question. And yes, the other answers work great too, they're more versitile for other applications as well. Mine just fits a need/want.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need to record, for any further reason, the fact that `connection` was *originally* passed as `None`, then you could overwrite that name:

```
if connection is None: connection = SetConnection()
self.connection = connection
```

Comment: While this is a valid syntax, *please don't format your code like this.* Put that inner line on it's own, indented line. [Compound statements are generally discouraged](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id28)

Answer (score 0):

My 2c using [isinstance](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/functions/isinstance.html) :

```
def __init__(self, connection=None, some=None, thing=None, else=None):
   if isinstance(connection, "class/type of connection") :
       self.connection = connection    
   else:
       self.connection = SetConnection()
```

---

Old answer:

```
self.connection = connection if connection else SetConnection()
```

---

PS: I'm not aware of the `class` or `type` of `connection`, if you also don't know it, use`type(connection)`

Comment: Same debate applies as to Jaba's answer:  this is probably OK given the context, but it makes the unstated assumption that 0, `False`, `[]`, `()`, `{}` and `''`  are not among the valid possibilities for  `connection`.

Comment: Noted. One solution would be using `isinstance` to assure `connection` is the instance we expect it to be.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, why not do

```
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.connection = kwargs.get('connection', SetConnection())
```

Which puts aside problems related to falsy values while being pythonic. That being said, it has other drawbacks for sure, e.g. those related to the idea of auto-documentability of the code.